# pyqt start timer only once

Tags: python, timer, pyqt, pyqt5

Is it possible to start the Qtimer only once if the time is up

```
self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
self.timer.setInterval(10000)
self.timer.start(800)  # start only once, not every 800 milliseconds
self.timer.timeout.connect(self.function)
```

Answer (score 3):

To do this you must enable the [`singleShot`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#singleShot-prop) property:

```
self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
self.timer.setSingleShot(True)
self.timer.setInterval(800)

self.timer.timeout.connect(self.function)

self.timer.start()
```

Or

```
QTimer.singleShot(800, self.function)
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides the signleShot method as eyllanesc mentioned,
you can just stop the timer in self.function.

```
def function(self):
    self.timer.stop()
```